"more hot questions" link is broken
When I visit a question, and then try to use the 'more hot questions' link in the sidebar, it doesn't work as advertised. Hovering over it shows me the URL of the post I'm currently on, and clicking on it redirects me to the shown URL:


I'm on Windows + Chrome, 126.0.6478.183, and disabled all addons/browser plugins/ userscripts I manually added to it while testing. Console looks like this

Can't reproduce at the moment with Firefox 128 on Windows. I'm also on  revision 2024.7.18.12879 of the site it's possible that a new update has not rolled out completely, so I'm on an older version. But also - maybe check your addons

No repro: Brave ( 1.67.134 Chromium: 126.0.6478.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)), Chrome (126.0.6478.182 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

@VLAZ of course, bad mod... forgot the version XD

Ooh, I might have an explanation - if the tab was still loading for some reason (maybe it was waiting on some resource) then clicking the "more hot questions" link would behave like you described. This might be caused by slow internet speed or maybe a random network spike or something. It can be simulated if you open the browser network tools: in Chrome and in Firefox. If you can reproduce it easily, see if the page shows up as loading (there should be an indicator in the tab it self).

@VLAZ nope, fully loaded: https://i.sstatic.net/xvCmM6iI.png and the same behaviour in an incognito tab as well (so it's not cookies or caching, is it?). Also not just this post, but several others on other sites too... I've tried a random arqade post, and one on law...

Any errors in the console?

@JourneymanGeek A few, no clue if they're relevant/what they mean https://i.sstatic.net/3oJQ2WlD.png

Given all hot questions are always already on the page, just hidden due to a class, I wonder why your console is riddled with errors that originate from content that I can't find on the page. Are you sure your ISP or Company firewall isn't playing tricks on you?

@rene Company firewall: No. I just checked my phone (loading a desktop site), does the same thing. ISP, how would I know? It's KPN, might as well be...

Well that's not really a link, it should trigger JS code that loads more hot questions, and something there is broken.

My idea is: try to load the page in Incognito mode of the browser. Does the "more hot questions" work there?

@ShadowWizard "the same behaviour in an incognito tab as well"

Did you test to see if you have this problem only on sites where you're a mod or on all sites?

@Makyen did you check whether I'm a mod on cooking, law, or arqade? ;) I don't mod those sites. And it doesn't work for me on MSE either, a site I do mod ;)

@Tinkeringbell No, as the only indication in the question of what site you're doing this on is an image with an alt text of "enter image description here".

@rene The errors shown in the console are all about an unchecked runtime.lastError. runtime.lastError is a browser extension API endpoint that's used to indicate an error in some asynchronous processes. Those console errors indicate that a browser extension didn't properly handle something. From the errors, the most likely thing is that communication between a content script and the background script was disrupted, either actively by the content script, or, much more likely, by the content script context being destroyed. Given the mention of "frame" I'd guess at an issue with iframes.

@Makyen I'm wondering which extension then, because it also happens on my phone and I have no manually added extensions there at all. So it's also not like I missed disabling something on the laptop...
